# Regex - Exclude a single word if it is the only word in string

Tags: regex, cpu-word

I'm looking for a regex that does not pass if a particular word is the only word typed (ignoring whitesapce). For example:

Accepted:

```
"Word hello"
"hello Word"
"Wordy"
```

Edit: Also would accept "hello hello"

Rejected:

```
"Word"
" Word"
"Word "
"   Word"
```

Edit: I didn't make my question very clear. Sorry. I meant that I only wanted it to reject the string when the word "Word" is the only thing in the string (ignoring whitespace).

Comment: What about `Word Word`?

Comment: Is `hello hello` also banned then?

Comment: For the record, the way you asked the question is a bit backwards - you want it to "not pass" yet your accepted matches are what you **don't** want. Suggest you reword either Accepted/Rejected or the original question.

Comment: VERY unclear question, as it seems to be required that "**Word**" has to be part of the match, but accepted answer doesn't take that into consideration...

Comment: The question never states that "Word" has to be part of the String, only to reject strings that _only_ contain it. And all the examples match that premise. The question is not VERY unclear but a little bit ambiguous, I guess.

Comment: I don't see why `regex` questions would need to turn into these downvote-fests. It's a bit telling that commenters ask for clarification only after their answers did not "win". ;) Have a good day.

Comment: That was my fault I guess for not putting and extra "hello hello" in the Accepted section. xsc's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually not sure if this works in general, but it looks good for your examples:

```
^(?!\s*Word\s*$).*
```

Comment: OP wants to match _everything_ that is not the single word "Word", possibly surrounded by whitespace, right? At least I don't see the requirement for "Word" being part of the string anywhere.

Comment: I don't think I was clear in my original post. Sorry about that. Yes this is the one that works for me. I didn't want "Word" to be the only thing in the string ignoring whitespace.

Comment: @user3046715 - Is this really what you want? This solution matches even empty string/input!

Comment: Yes. I only want it to reject when the word "Word" is the only thing in the string while ignoring whitespace. Empty is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If `Word` is required to be a part of match, then use regular expression pattern

```
^(?!\s*Word\s*$)\s*\K.*Word.*?(?=\s*$)
```

If not, go with

```
^(?!\s*Word\s*$)\s*\K.*\S
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the most graceful example, but it seems to pass your criteria:

```
\S+.*Word.*|.*Word.*\S+
```

---

To match the entire line, which seemed to be the intent:

```
^.*\S+.*Word.*|.*Word.*\S+.*$
```

Comment: This will match BobWord and WordBob, so that doesn't do the job.

Comment: I believe `Wordy` was listed as an accepted string, which is basically the same as `WordBob`.

Comment: What about `: Word :` string - it would not match, but should!

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ: if you referred to the `:` character, I didn't feel the question was clear enough on non-`\w`-characters, so I stuck to word characters.

Comment: @lime - Okay, your choice, you might be right, but imagine **One-Word** string - your solution will not match it.

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ, good point and a fair assumption. Will switch to `\S`.

Answer (score -1):

`^\s*\w*Word\w*\s*$`

Will do the job, provided you're matching the beginning and end of string.

Otherwise, you'll need to do something funky with lookarounds:

`^(?<!\w)(\s*\w*Word\w*\s*)+(?!\w)$`

If you need it to only match one occurrence of 'Word', then:

`^(?<!\w)(\s*\w*Word\w*\s*){1}(?!\w)$`

**Matches:**

- "Word "
- "  Word"
- " myWord"

**Non-matches:**

- "Word Word"
- "Word Bob"
- "a Word"
- "   a Word"